# Should I test CQRS Handlers or the whole request output in Web Api Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cqrs, mediatr

I've been creating Web API for a while and was happy to be able to test CQRS Handlers (managed with Mediatr) without touching on any kind of infrastructure code (controllers, requets, etc.).And it made total sense as my controllers were extremely thin as they were doing what controllers are supposed to do: communicate between request and response:

```
    [HttpGet("requests")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<AbsenceRequest>> GetAbsenceRequests(GetAbsenceRequests.Query query)
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(query);
    }
```

But still there were cases that my Handlers tests did not cover. Here's a couple of examples:

1. Authorization. I could not test if a "wrong" user tried to access a
   specific action, he received denied access error. In other words, I could not tests authorization attributes for a specific action.
2. Error handling. I could check that my Handler threw a specific
       exception under specific conditions but I could not control how
       infrastructure (i. e. exception middleware) handled this exception
       (i. e. resulted in a specific HTTP error).

ASP.NET Core made request-in response-out integration tests extremely easy (thanks to TestServer) and I can cover those two cases in my integration tests.

The question that bothers me is whether I should keep Handlers tests or test actions by sending requests and asserting the response instead.

I really love Handler tests. They're cute, clear and easy to write. Testing the whole request is much more powerful but at the same time messier as it's a relatively low-level approach and you have to deal with http and json.

I find this choice very confusing and would like to know what is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would test your handlers using unit tests, because these tests can run more quickly and should be less brittle than testing the handlers through MVC. There's no good reason to couple all of your tests of your handlers to your current MVC implementation. When making a decision about whether to write a unit test or an integration test, the question should be "Can I test this with a unit test?" If the answer is yes, then write a unit test.

Now, that said, integration tests in ASP.NET Core using `TestServer` are awesome (I wrote [the docs on them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing)). There are things you *can't* test with a unit test (of your handler or of a controller action method), like whether your routes are set up correctly, or your MVC error handling, or filters, or model binding. You should write tests to confirm this behavior, using integration tests and `TestServer` (if you think they add value, that is). You shouldn't test all the same scenarios you already have unit tests for - that would be a waste. But you can verify different things that your unit tests couldn't by using this approach.

Comment: Thanks for really good feedback! I just wanted to correct one thing. Handlers tests are not unit tests, they're integration tests (they go through in-memory database). So it's a choice between integration tests of different scale. But I agree, despite how great TestServer is, we should test through it only things we can not test on a lower level.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping tests because: 'They're cute' i wouldn't really use as an argument.

Why do you test?

- To make sure software that is delivered works (eg NASA spaceship software)
- Reduce time spending afterwards on fixing bugs
- Reduce time to finish a project

Automated tests are awesome cause they can catch bugs consistently. But if tests are only easy to write and have no benefit further than that, i would say they are useless and you should remove them.

On the other side, automated unit tests definitely have their place. Since they catch bug at development time, and are thus easiest and quickest to fix. when you run your tests only at release time or are only possible in ci build the downside is that a developer has to be put on the issue 'again'.

For you as experienced software engineer/Project leader, it's to decide what will benefit you the most for your project.